# Passing PHP variable to Javascript in PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, google-polyline

I'm currently developing a PHP page which gets information on various attributes from an API, the values of which are held in PHP variables.

One of these variables is a Google Maps encoded Polyline which I'd like to plot and include in the PHP page.

I have the working code for crating the Polyline using the Google Maps API.  What I'd like to do is, instead of using the polyline string in the Javascript, pass the PHP variable (which contains the string) to the Javascript.

This page plots the polyline successfully:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Simple Polylines</title>
        <style>
            html, body, #map {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;libraries=geometry&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=XXX"></script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function initialize() {
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.65905179951626, 7.3835928124999555);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: myLatlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

                var decodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath('}~kvHmzrr@ba\\hnc@jiu@r{Zqx~@hjp@pwEhnc@zhu@zflAbxn@fhjBvqHroaAgcnAp}gAeahAtqGkngAinc@_h|@r{Zad\\y|_D}_y@swg@ysg@}llBpoZqa{@xrw@~eBaaX}{uAero@uqGadY}nr@`dYs_NquNgbjAf{l@|yh@bfc@}nr@z}q@i|i@zgz@r{ZhjFr}gApob@ff}@laIsen@dgYhdPvbIren@');
                var decodedLevels = decodeLevels("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB");

                var setRegion = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: decodedPath,
                    levels: decodedLevels,
                    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    map: map
                });
            }

            function decodeLevels(encodedLevelsString) {
                var decodedLevels = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < encodedLevelsString.length; ++i) {
                    var level = encodedLevelsString.charCodeAt(i) - 63;
                    decodedLevels.push(level);
                }
                return decodedLevels;
            }


            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I had to remove the API key for obvious reasons.

So in the example above, I'd like to pass a PHP variable (let's call it `$polyline`) as the Javascript variable "`var decodePath`"

How do I do this whille keeping the page formatted correctly in PHP?  (all my attempts so far as reulted in various PHP syntax errors.

Comment: var decodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath('<?php echo something; ?>');

Comment: Define variable in the fine before your <script> tag and use it in the google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath('<?php echo $variablename; ?>')